# NestJS and Mongoose find by reference object Id

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I have a Mongo collection of Users and a collection of Addresses. Each address is owned by one user.Here are my schema classes:

```
export type UserDocument = User & mongoose.Document
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class User {
  // @Prop({ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId })
  _id: string

  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string

  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  email: string

  @Prop({ select: false })
  password: string

}
export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User)

export type AddressDocument = Address & Document
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Address {
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: User.name })
  user: User

  @Prop()
  line1: string

  @Prop()
  line2?: string

  @Prop()
  city: string

  @Prop()
  state?: string

  @Prop()
  country: string
}

export const AddressSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Address)
```

Then I have an AddressService that can fetch addresses for a user:

```
@Injectable()
export class AddressService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Address.name) private addressModel: Model<AddressDocument>) {}

  async save(address: AddressDto): Promise<Address> {
    const model = await this.addressModel.create(address)
    return model.save()
  }

  async findAddressForUser(userId: string) {
    const userObjectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)
    const users = await this.addressModel.find({ user: userObjectId })
  }
}
```

This code has an error: `Type '_ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Condition<User>`
I tried passing the userId as a string as well, that did not work either.

What is the right way to query a collection using a reference Id from another collection?

Comment: have you been able to find the proper way to find data by reference using props model and mongoose. If so can you please share. Im struggling finding it out.

Comment: @YerfA42 check the answer I added. That works.

Answer (score 18):

I think the `user` field shouldn't be of type `User`, despite what the NestJS docs say. It should be of type `Types.ObjectId`.

Something like this (with cleaner imports aswell):

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { SchemaTypes, Types, Document } from 'mongoose';

export type AddressDocument = Address & Document
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Address {
  @Prop({ type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: User.name })
  user: Types.ObjectId;

  ...

}
export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User)
```

I got this from [here](https://doug-martin.github.io/nestjs-query/docs/persistence/mongoose/relations/).

You could also tell TypeScript that this may be either a string, an ObjectId or a User by declaring it as: `user: string | Types.ObjectId | UserDocument;`

Comment: This helped me. Thanks a lot for sharing your solution

Comment: The problem with this is when you populate the field, you need a type guard function in order to narrow `string | Types.ObjectId | UserDocument`

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is the proper way of doing this but this is what I ended up doing to get around that error:

```js
  async findAddressForUser(userId: string): Promise<Address[]> {
    const query: any = { user: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) }
    return await this.addressModel.find(query).exec()
  }
```

Comment: this works but the 'any' type looks bad...
Wondering why it doesn't work if you add FilterQuery< AddressDocument > instead.

That would give the same error Type '_ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Condition<User>

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked:

```js
async findModulesUser(id: string) {
    const record = await this.modulesuserModel
      .find({ user: new Types.ObjectId(id) })
      .populate("user", ["name", "email"])
      .exec();

    return record;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31138584)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after reviewing all of your answer, i saw that i had already resolved the question by a certain way somewhere in my app.

So basically what work on my side:

```
@ObjectType()
export class Account implement AccountInterface{
  ...some properties
  //to manage Parent relation
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
  owner: User;
  
  //to manage Children relation
  @Prop([{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }])
  users?: [User];
}
```

My AccountInterface

```
export interface AccountInterface {
  //some properties
  owner: User;
  users: [Users]
}
```

seems to work without problem.

```
const account = await this.accountModel.find({
  owner: user._id,
});
```

However you need to define the way data should be fetch from parent and children. The answer above from EzPizza appears to be the best way to handle relationship.